# SAXUnmarshaller java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting the below exception while unmarshalling the xml content. I am running under weblogic 12c and have xercerimpl.jar & xalan.jar jars packaged inside the war. Please let know what could be the problem for this error.

```
Exception Description: An error occurred while trying to instantiate the schema platform.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.errorInstantiatingSchemaPlatform(XMLMarshalException.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.getXMLReader(SAXUnmarshaller.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.unmarshal(SAXUnmarshaller.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLUnmarshaller.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.unmarshal(JAXBUnmarshaller.java:149)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.setEntityResolver(AbstractSAXParser.java:1177)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.XMLReader.setEntityResolver(XMLReader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.SAXUnmarshaller.getXMLReader(SAXUnmarshaller.java:166
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following as a workaround to get an `EntityResolver` in the right spot:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBHelper;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLUnmarshaller;
import org.xml.sax.EntityResolver;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Demo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        JAXBUnmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBHelper.getUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
        XMLUnmarshaller xmlUnmarshaller = jaxbUnmarshaller.getXMLUnmarshaller();
        xmlUnmarshaller.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {

            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                    throws SAXException, IOException {
                return null;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

---

> I am running under weblogic 12c and have xercerimpl.jar & xalan.jar
>   jars packaged inside the war.

Why do you have xerceimpl.jar and xalan.jar packaged inside your war?

> Those jars are added by the component into my war project by Maven.

I would recommend fixing this in your Maven setup.

---

### UPDATE

> The unmarschalling logic is written in seperate component which they
>   can't change it (works for other projects). Is there away i can fix it
>   in my side (inside web project)? Here is the component code,
>   JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class); Unmarshaller
>   unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller(); Result result = (Config)
>   unmarshaller.unmarshal(url);

Try the following it will cause MOXy to go down a path that leverages a StAX parser instead of a SAX one:

```
InputStream inputStream = url.openStream;
Result result = (Config) unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream);
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Blaise, Thanks for your reply. The unmarschalling logic is written in seperate component which they can't change it (works for other projects). Is there away i can fix it in my side (inside web project)? Here is the component code,   

JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Result result = (Config) unmarshaller.unmarshal(url);                          

Those jars are added by the component into my war project by Maven.

Comment: @skumar - What does the XML look like that you are sending?

Comment: xml,

<Information>
 <params>
  <param>
   <param-name>name</param-name>
   <param-value>app1</param-value>
  </param>
  <param>
   <param-name>Information-changer</param-name>
   <param-value>com.test.Changer</param-value>
  </param>
 </params>
 <classs>
  <class>
   <class-name>class1</class-name>
   </class-actions>
   <class-params>
    <class-param>
     <param-name>enabled</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
    </class-param>  
   </class-params>
  </class>
 </classs>
</Information>

Comment: @skumar - I have updated my answer with an approach that should work.

Comment: I guess your proposed changes need an update in the component level. Do you have any other solution? I debugged the code and found that the component used file param instead of url for unmarshalling. Config result = (Config) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Comment: @skumar - What is different between your scenario and the other ones which are working?

Comment: @Blasie, I really dont know what exactly the difference. may be my project have some extra jars.